# Can I get common parameters from parent constructor?

Tags: python, oop

I would like to know if I can use the parent constructor for passing parameters which will be needed for every subclass. So for instance:

```
Class A():
    def __init__(a,b):
    ...do some stuff...

Class B(A):
    def __init__(c,d):
     ...do some stuff needing a and b...

Class C(A):
    def __init__(e,f,g):
     ...do some stuff needing a and b...
```

Basically there are some parameters each of my subclasses is going to want and some others which are specific. I don't want to have to add a,b to the definition of every subclass of A. Is there some way I can do this in python?

What I'd like to see is the ability to call:

```
b=B(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
```

without having to include a and b in the subclass definition.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Python 3, but the idea is the same in 2

class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        # ...

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, c, d, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, e, f, g, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```